# Lazy view of java.util.Collection in Vavr

Tags: java, vavr

I have an existing api which uses `java.util.Collection` when returning values. I would like to use those values in later parts of my program with Vavr but I don't want to use the eager methods like `List.ofAll` (because I do not want to traverse those `Collection` objects twice). My use case is something like this:

```
List<Product> filter(java.util.Collection products) {
    return List.lazyOf(products).filter(pred1);
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: This question is not clear for me. What are you worrying about precisely? What do you mean by _interfere with the whole idea of immutability_? Give an example.

Comment: Will this “list” only be used/traversed once?  If so you want to return a `Stream<Product>`.   Your stream can include a `filter(...)`.  The stream will not be traversed until the caller uses a terminal operation on the stream.

Comment: Like I said, I want to use the Vavr List<Product> in later parts of the program so simply using Java Stream api is not really what I want. My goal is to avoid the overhead of creating (eagerly) the Vavr list from the products Collection. I reckon that filter will create a new list either way, so the initial copying of the list (by List.ofAll) is unnecessary (from my perspective, but maybe not from Vavr perspective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the input collection to the method is a java `Collection`, you cannot rely on immutability, so you need to process the values contained in the collection right away. You cannot defer this to a later point in time as there is no guarantee the passed collection remains unchanged.

You can minimize the number of vavr `List`s built by doing the filtering on an iteration of the passed collection, then collecting the result to a `List`.

```java
import io.vavr.collection.Iterator;
import io.vavr.collection.List;
...

List<Product> filter(Collection<Product> products) {
    return Iterator.ofAll(products)
        .filter(pred1)
        .collect(List.collector());
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I think they should mention it in their Interoperability chapter of their docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Lazy](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/blob/master/vavr/src/main/java/io/vavr/Lazy.java) class in vavr. You might want to use it.

```
Lazy<Option<Integer>> val1 = Lazy.of(() -> 1).filter(i -> false);
```

Comment: Using Lazy here will simply produce a Value with the list as an element. Filter will receive the whole list as an argument and not its elements.

    Lazy.of(() -> Arrays.asList("a","b","c")).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));